# spark-submit NoSuchMethodError BigDecimalDeserializer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I have scala code which uses the Htable class of Hbase , I am building that as jar and running using spark-submit like below

```
spark2-submit --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.11.0-1.cdh5.11.0.p0.34/lib/hbase/lib/* --class commontest    scala-maven-plugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am passing the hbase class path using extraClassPath , but still getting below error, has anyone got this error ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer$.handledType()Ljava/lang/Class;
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.NumberDeserializers$.<init>(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala:49)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.NumberDeserializers$.<clinit>(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.ScalaNumberDeserializersModule$class.$init$(ScalaNumberDeserializersModule.scala:61)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:20)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:37)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$.<clinit>(DefaultScalaModule.scala)
at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.<init>(JsonProtocol.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.<clinit>(JsonProtocol.scala)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$.initEventLog(EventLoggingListener.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:531)
at KPICommonDeviceDayUsage$.main(KPICommonDeviceDayUsage.scala:339)
at KPICommonDeviceDayUsage.main(KPICommonDeviceDayUsage.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.deser.BigDecimalDeserializer$.handledType()Ljava/lang/Class;

This exception indicates that you have multiple versions of the library available at run-time.

Comment: how to know where are the multiple version of same lib are added or force to include only one version of lib